# Kernel of group homomorphism

Tags: group-homomorphism

Is there a homomorphism with the domain $S_{10}$ whose kernel is {e, (12)}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the kernel is always a normal subgroup. Is the subgroup you are considering a normal subgroup?